# conditional statment in prompt

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, getelementbyid, prompt

I'm working on providing a user with two different pictures depending on the right username/password. I'm having a prompt popup for the user to give the username/password and after providing the right credentials the login picture should appear and if the credentials are wrong the logout picture should appear. I am using the getElementById to change accordingly. At this moment the prompt shows up, but there is no picture showing.

```html
<img src="user_in.PNG" id="user_in_id" hidden>
<img src="user_out.PNG" id="user_out_id" hidden>

<script> 
      
     var person = prompt("Please enter your name", ""); 
     var password = prompt("Please enter your password", "");
     if (person == "admin" && password =="admin") {
        alert("Welcome, You are now Logged in");
        document.getElementById("user_in_id");

      }else
        alert("wrong username or password");
        document.getElementById("user_out_id");
      
</script>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the results of `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: If you want to display the image, add `.hidden = false`

Comment: Unrelated, but sometimes it's helpful to think about naming things w/ a common (e.g., here, `user_logged_`) and updating just the suffix. It can help normalize things across multiple related, but different, elements.

Comment: You need `document.getElementById("user_in_id").removeAttribute('hidden');` or some other way of actually *doing* something. getElementById, as the *get* implies, grabs the element for further commands but doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: The "get" element grabs the element and I'm not doing anything with the grabbed get element. I would need to create a variable holding the new picture and replace it with the "get" one. Something like this:  var x= document.getElementById('user_in_id');
  s.value = 'New value'. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply a function to your `document.getElementById("user_in_id")` selector,which somehow makes the selected element visible.

One way would be to remove the `hidden` attribute from it with `document.getElementById("user_in_id").removeAttribute("hidden");`

You also forgot to wrap your `else` statement around curly brackets in order to work properly.

```html
<img src="https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_3obin/styles/communityIcon_5v6pv5kqz5241.PNG" id="user_in_id" hidden>
<img src="https://public.blenderkit.com/thumbnails/assets/0992088bfb844c69bb6e426272970c8b/files/thumbnail_c858218a-4afc-4e94-b6b9-080f5e6c7066.jpg.256x256_q85_crop-%2C.jpg" id="user_out_id" hidden>

<script>
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", ""); 
    var password = prompt("Please enter your password", "");
     if (person === "admin" && password === "admin") {
        alert("Welcome, You are now Logged in");
        document.getElementById("user_in_id").removeAttribute("hidden");

      }else{ 
       alert("wrong username or password");
       document.getElementById("user_out_id").removeAttribute("hidden");
      }
        
      
</script>
```